# How to make search bar using js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html-table

WHAT I WANT TO DO : I want to make a search bar for my table using js.

WHAT I HAVE : I have a html table having data from database .

WHAT I TRY : I tried this code to retrieve result but its not working. Here is my full code:

```
<div class="box-tools">

                <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
                    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">


                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
              <table class="table table-hover" id="myTable">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <th style="width: 10px">ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Image</th>
                  <th style="width: 40px">Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($check as $row)
                 {?>
                <tr>


                  <td><?php echo $row['cat_id'];?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row['category_name'];?></td>
                  <td><img src="<?php echo $row['category_image'];?>" height="100" width="100"></td>
                  <td><a href="editcategory.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['cat_id']);?>"><button class=" btn btn-primary btn-warning" >Edit<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></a>
                  <td><a href="deletecategory.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['cat_id']);?>" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google"><i class="fa fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
 <?php  } ?>
                </tr>
              </tbody></table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>


          </section>
      </div>
```

When I try to search it gives me empty results.

Comment: what is not working , You at all not getting val of td or the conditions are not getting fulfilled?

Comment: Your code seems to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/5nfmt8Lk/) ..?

Comment: got empty result  nothing display when i search

Comment: how can i serch for category nam i tried it work over id

Comment: any suggestion to search for name

Comment: Your code explicitly searches from the first cell of the rows only. You've to iterate all the cells for every row, if you want to include other cells to the search. Or compare keyword to `textContent` of a row instead of the innerHTML of the cells.

Comment: if nothing found on result how can i display the no result found on table help with code please am new to js

Comment: See how to use textContent: https://jsfiddle.net/5nfmt8Lk/2/ I suppose you actually don't need such an announcement, since the table becomes empty if nothing found. Notice, that I've moved the `id` from the table to the tbody, that way the headers are excluded from the search.